# How to keep the coordinates of the nodes using graphviz

Tags: graph, coordinates, graphviz

I have a question about graphviz: I am working in a representation of a project; I'm using graphviz but I would like to know if it is possible to keep the coordinates of the nodes of the version **n-1** that will be present in the version **n** of my project.

I really need to keep as much as possible the similarities between the 2 graphs. I've been looking for possible similar questions but the answer are not useful in my case. By the way, I'm using the command twopi (I don't know if this is relevant for in this question).

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have graphs of both version **n** and version **n-1** available, then you could *diff* the `plain` versions of the graphs (see the answer to [graphviz - compare graphic trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655065/graphviz-compare-graphic-trees/) for how to do that), strip out and apply to the version **n-1** graph only the additions indicated in the *diff* file to generate a merged graph that includes all of the nodes that are in either graph **n** or **n-1**.

You could then process the merged graph with a script that, perhaps, colored the nodes differently to indicate if they are in both versions, only in version **n** or only in version **n-1**. That could be done with a script in Python, Perl or Awk, for instance. You can find a Python script that shows how to process a Graphviz script in order to produce a somewhat different effect in an answer to [What is the best way to draw large graph using graphvis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173764/what-is-the-best-way-to-draw-large-graph-using-graphvis/).

A simpler version of this problem would only add nodes from one version to the next. That case has been discussed in [Node graph layout library for incremental graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792847/node-graph-layout-library-for-incremental-graphs/).

Comment: Thank you thank you so much Simon. I'm going to follow your advices.